# How can I see all the colorbar labels with custom ticks and logarithmic transformation?

Tags: matplotlib, logarithm, colorbar

When using custom ticks and LogNorm(), only power of 10 labels are displayed, not all labels.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy.random import random

# Make plot with horizontal colorbar
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = random((250,250)) + 3.5

norm = matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(vmin=0.1,vmax=10)

cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.afmhot, norm=norm)
ax.set_title('Gaussian noise with horizontal colorbar')

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10], orientation='horizontal')

plt.savefig("example.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a complete but minimal example of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `format` option:

```
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[0.1,0.2,0.5,1,2,5,10], 
                    orientation='horizontal', format='%.1f')
```

This moves away from the representation as `10^n` (which struggles with `0.5` for example) to floating point numbers:

[image: all ticks labeled]